# unnecessary extra rerender in component cause removing field's value

Tags: reactjs, redux, components

I'm using React and redux and I have a scenario. I have four actions which one of them depends on other two.
If we have `this.props.fetch1()`, `this.props.fetch2()`, `this.props.fetch3()`, first I need to receive the result of `this.props.fetch1()` and `this.props.fetch2()` and then use the `id` filed of each result to make the request to server by redux like this:

```
1.
  this.props.fetch1()
  this.props.fetch2()

2.
  this.props.fetchResult1.id1
  this.props.fetchResult2.id2

3.
  this.props.fetch3(this.props.fetchResult1.id1, this.props.fetchResult1.id2)

4.
  this.props.fetchResult3

5.
  show the list on the page
```

and then by using `this.props.fetchResult3` which is an array, I'm making a list to show on the page at the time of rendering page.

The problem is that because this actions are asynchronous the result is not ready to use. I used `shouldComponentUpdate` to render until result is ready but it's stopping states from updating in other part and even if I compare states to update it will rerender the component which in my case will cause to reset my fields value on the page by each change in state.(I have 2 text input and one checkbox on page for submission)

```
shouldComponentUpdate(nextProps, nextState, nextContext) {
        return !isEqual(nextProps.fetchResult1, this.props.fetchResult1) ||
               !isEqual(nextProps.fetchResult2, this.props.fetchResult2) ||
               !isEqual(nextState.fetchResult2, this.state.fetchResult2)

    }


componentDidMount() {
        this.callfetch1fetch2();
    }


componentDidUpdate(prevProps, prevState, snapshot) {
        if (prevProps.fetchResult1 === this.props.fetchResult1 && !this.props.fetchResult2) {
            this.callfetch1fetch2();
        } else {
            this.callfetch3();
        }
}
```

I want to know the best way to handle this that prevents rerendering but also updating state correctly.

Thanks in advance for any suggestion.

Answer (score 1):

You can use:

```
Promise.all([
  this.props.fetch1(),
  this.props.fetch2()
]).then(response => {
// do something
})
```

or create one function async/await

```
async function getResults() {
   let fetchResult1 = await this.props.fetch1(),
   let fetchResult2 = await this.props.fetch1()
}
```

Comment: but still the result of `fetch1` is not available, I'm calling `getResults()` in `componentDidMount`

Answer (score 0):

Use promises for this scenario.

Your component will call only single `fetchAll` in `componentDidMount` and `componentDidUpdate` (you need to do it in some `if` in `componentDidUpdate` - only when it is necessary to reload data from server).

Map only `fetchResult3` to your component if you do not need to display `fetchResult1` and `fetchResult2`.

```js
function fetchAll() {
    return (dispatch) => {
        return Promise.all([
            dispatch(fetch1()),
            dispatch(fetch2())
        ]).then(([fetchResult1, fetchResult2]) =>
            dispatch(fetchResult3(fetchResult1.id, fetchResult2.id))
        );
    };
}
```

Comment: but still the result of `fetch1` is not available, I'm calling `fetchAll()` in `componentDidMount`

Comment: You have to handle the case when your asynchronous data are not available in component `render` function. E.g.: if necessary data are not available yet, return `null`. `shouldComponentUpdate` should be used only for performance improvements. If you have mapped your state to props correctly, the component will rerender whenever mapped data has changed (i.e. after asynchronous action creator dispatches action and reducer changes state).